# Restriction of a group homomorphism to a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $f:G\to G$ is a group homomorphism and let $N\trianglelefteq G$. What can we say about $f$ if restriction of $f$ to $N$ is an identity on $N$? Can we say anything "nice" in this situation.

Comment: we can say that $f$ induces a homomorphism $\bar{f}:G/N \to G$ defined by $\bar{f}(gN) = f(g)$.

Comment: @Derek Holt, my condition does not say $f(N)=1$, but $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in N$.

Comment: Ah, sorry!, I misunderstood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\ker f\cap N=\{e\}$ so $N\ker f\cong N\times\ker f$ and $N\ker f$ is normal in $G$.
2. if $|G:N|=n$ then $f(g)^n=g^n$ for all $g\in G$.
3. $\bar f:G/N\to G/N$ by $gN\mapsto f(g)N$ is an homomorphism.

**proof:**

1. obvious.
2. since $g^n\in N$ and  $f(x)=x$ for $x\in N$ the result follows.
3. since $f(gx)=f(g)x$ for $x\in N$ the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be the kernel of $f.$ We can say that $N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/K,$ since your condition guarantees that $f$ embeds $N$ isomorphically as a subgroup of ${\rm im} f.$